# Substring doesn't return proper text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I have little trouble understanding why variables aren't working properly in the following code.

```
var welcomeMsg = $('#accountbar span.welcome_text').text(); // This returns "Welcome, Nick(account)      "
var cutdown = welcomeMsg.slice(0, -6); // This removes excessive spaces after (account) 
cutdown = cutdown.slice(cutdown.indexOf(",")+2,cutdown.indexOf("(")); // returns "Nick"

var username = cutdown;  // "Nick" //This doesn't work with last line of the script
//alert(username);
//var username = "Nick"  // but this works if it's used instead of  var username = cutdown;
//alert(username);

$("td:contains('"+username+"')").parent().css({
    "background" : "url('http://imagehost.com/forum/row1.png')"
});
```

It's for a Greasemonkey script, if that matters.

**Solved:**
It seems that `.trim` is better way to delete excessive spaces around the wanted string.
The script works perfectly for me if this

```
var cutdown = welcomeMsg.slice(0, -6); // This removes excessive spaces after (account) 
cutdown = cutdown.slice(cutdown.indexOf(",")+2,cutdown.indexOf("("));
```

is replaced with this

```
var cutdown = welcomeMsg.slice(welcomeMsg.indexOf(",")+2,welcomeMsg.indexOf("("));
cutdown = cutdown.trim();
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution to your issue but please note that you can answer you own question (it is even [highly recommended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)) and accept it. This way, you can share your knowledge with the community and kind of *close* the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`.trim` fixed the problem when it is used instead of `.slice`

Answer (score 1):

The `slice()` and `indexOf()` method does not reliably cut the cruft around the user name.  Use regex for a more robust/flexible approach.

Also, Even if the correct row was selected, just setting background like that might appear to fail due to server issues, hotlink blocking, etc.  Set a color as a backup if the image load doesn't take.  Consider `@require`ing the image to reduce server dependencies (a subject for/covered by other questions).

Here's code that should work a little better.  ([**See it in action at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sxYZf/)):

```
var welcomeMsg  = $('#accountbar span.welcome_text').text ();
var userName    = welcomeMsg.replace (
    /^\s*Welcome,\s*([^\(]+)\((?:\n|\r|.)+$/i, 
    "$1"
);
userName        = $.trim (userName);

$("tr:contains('" + userName + "')").css ( {
    "background-color": "lime",
    "background-image": "url('http://imagehost.com/forum/row1.png')"
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working Fine for me.. I am using **color** instead of the **image**

[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/QVEfe/1/)

```
var welcomeMsg="Welcome, Nick(account)      " // This returns "Welcome, Nick(account)    "

console.log("'" + welcomeMsg + "'");

var cutdown = welcomeMsg.slice(0, -6); // This removes excessive spaces after (account) 

console.log("'" + cutdown + "'");
cutdown = cutdown.slice(cutdown.indexOf(",")+2,cutdown.indexOf("(")); // returns "Nick"

console.log("'" +cutdown+ "'");
var username = cutdown;  

$("td:contains('"+username+"')").parent().css({   "color" : "red"});​
```

Comment: It does seem to work as a normal javascript. But it doesn't work as a Greasemonkey script. Here's part of the site and the script http://jsfiddle.net/7QEPV/1/

Comment: Did you try using color or backgroundColor instead of an image  ?? .. In your greasemonkey code

Comment: Yes. The `.css` selector works fine. Only problem is that cutdown is never === Nick. It just doesn't return same thing. Script works if I'm using `var username = "Nick";` but not when I'm using `var username = cutdown;`